# javascript object, concatenate duplicate keys while keeping multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting

I have javascript objects that follow this pattern. Keys are to the left of the = sign, values to the right. The keys that are duplicates need to be concatenated to one key while keeping all the values.

```
var arrUnique = ['arTitle=randomword','arTitle=random','beTitle=rand1','bnTitle=whatever','caTitle=mango','caTitle=mangoes']
```

Becomes this string:

```
 arTitle = ['randomword','random' ], beTitle = ['rand1'], bnTitle = ['whatever'], caTitle = ['mango','mangoes']
```

Here is where I am at so far. Create an object with all the keys using regex. Then create a regex construction which loops through each object in keys and pushes to x only when it matches more then 1.

```
var keys = (/\w{2}Title=/gi);
var x = [];
    for (i = 0; i < arrUniqueCount; i++){ 
var regexp = new RegExp(keys[i], "gi");
var str2 = arrUniqueString.match(regexp).length;
    if (str2 > 1){
    x.push(regexp[i])} 
}
alert("repeats: " + x);
```

Next I was thinking of using regex to replace and match etc to finally get my outcome. I am finding this stage difficult. Would anybody mind sharing a better way?

Comment: Why not just split along `=` for each entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the route of just sliptting at the '=' sign then adding them to an object based on the key at index position 0 of that split.

```js
var arrUnique = ['arTitle=randomword', 'arTitle=random', 'beTitle=rand1', 'bnTitle=whatever', 'caTitle=mango', 'caTitle=mangoes'];
//object to collect the final result in
var result = {};

//go through each item and split on the equal
//this will create an array or arrays that contain your key/value
arrUnique.map(function(x) {
    return x.split("=");
}).forEach(function(item) {
    //if the key doesn;t yet exist in the object declare it as an empty array
    if (!result[item[0]]) {
        result[item[0]] = [];
    }
  
    //push the value onto this key
    result[item[0]].push(item[1]);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: oh re reading the question do you want the result to be an object or a full string?

Comment: Good job, although it looks more natural to use `reduce` for the second step.

Comment: cheers, in this situation I think forEach reads better as im not really reducing the array to one value rather using the data  located at each index to do something in another object

Comment: `result` is precisely the value to which you reduce - and `reduce` would make the point clear. But that's a matter of style/taste, of course.

Comment: ah ok, i've always though about reduced when i'm letting the items in the array interact to get to one particular value (doing something with previous and current items). Looking at it where `result` is the product of reducing the array i see where you are coming from. Cheers

Comment: Great solution, much better then the route I was taking. Yes, to answer your first comment I do need the final result as a string.  I will use stringify.